# Looking at polar representation of wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for all resources where the wavefunction has been seperated into polar form:

$$ \psi = \sqrt{\rho} e^{i \phi} .$$

I know this leads to non-linear weirdness, but I am okay with that. I understand this leads to something like the [Madelung Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_equations), but there are very few resources I know that go into this approach in depth. What is the best book/tutorial out there for this representation of the wavefunction?

Comment: You mean like in the [pilot wave theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_wave_theory)?

Comment: Why not replace $\sqrt{\rho}$ with a function $f$, I cannot see the difference, just symbols.

Comment: because $\rho$ has a special meaning, it is the probability density.